# Looping files in bash when they are in different locations

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, declare

I'm trying to create a for loop in bash which uses two different files (with same prefix). For example:

> /home/samples - Contains files A.fq B.fq etc
>
> /home/annotation - Contains files A.tab B.tab etc

I call their names in two separate arrays:

> filepathsfq=( /home/samples/*fq )
>
> filepathstab=( /home/anottation/*tab )

Now I want to call in a command

```
paste "${filepathsfq[@]##*/}" "${filepathstab[@]##*/}"
```

Such that I get, in a loop:

```
A.fq A.tab
B.fq B.tab
```

In my speficic case, the first 10 characters of each prefix should be equal!

I tried to create pairs in arrays without much success (with declare command)

such as:

> samples=("${filepathsfq[@]##*/}")
>
> declare -A tabs=("${filepathsrtab[@]##*/}")

> for sample in "${samples[@]}"; do
>
> echo "$sample is the same as > ${tabs[$sample]}"
>
> done

Of course this one above does not check for matching prefixes and would not work properly if some file does not contain a proper pair.

I've tried readarray without success because my first code

> filepathsfq=( /home/samples/*fq )

Is already an array and I can't redirect it to readarray

Comment: What if the first directory contains `xxxxxxxxxx1.fq` and `xxxxxxxxxx2.fq`, and the second directory contains `xxxxxxxxxxa.tab` and `xxxxxxxxxxb.tab`?

Comment: The closing reference doesn't address the question